# How to apply step when iterating over string characters?

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to apply a step during iteration? I have seen a reference to `step_by()` in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/iterators.html) but I cant seem to get it to work.

For example, to print every-other character of a string I can do this but is there an easier way?

```rust
let s1 = "whhaatt".to_string();

for letter in s1.chars().enumerate() {
    let (i, l) = letter;
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        println!("{:?}", l );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: *chars* return code-points, not necessarily what is graphically represented as a single character, hope that's alright with you,

Comment: Note: I found the referenced [step_by](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.StepBy.html) and it is only implemented for `Range` and `RangeFrom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the [`step` adaptor from the `itertools` crate](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.step).  In this case, you could use `s1.chars().step(2)`.

> *Aside*: Your code *does not* iterate over "characters"; it iterates over *code points*.  It's quite likely that you want the [`graphemes` method from the `unicode-segmentation` crate](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes).

Comment: Thanks, was the syntax for step_by() changed to setp()?

Comment: `.step_by` is only for ranges. `.step()` is for all iterators (it might be slow because of this)